# How Offline Data persistance for Desktop app with electron Framework can be done?

Tags: sqlite, electron, desktop-application

I am using Angular 5 application and using electron FrameWork to convert it to
desktop application and its working fine.

- How to persist about 10000 records of datasets in JSON form in desktop client side. So that whenever a user is in the offline mode he/she will be still able to use our application.
- Even user in offline mode can use the app and must be able to use our application even after he is restarting the system and even data should be secured and not exposed to the user as like local storage.